# How to reference a class method in a class attribute?

Tags: python, class-method, class-attribute

In a package, I have isolated a set of functions/variables that work altogether in a class. As these functions did not require a specific context, they became class methods. They may use some external functions, here represented by the `save_c` function. But I can't get the following code to work:

```
def save_c(v):
    print("c :" + v)


class Writer(object):

    @classmethod
    def save(cls, t, v):
        cls.writers[t](v)


    @classmethod
    def save_a(cls, v):
        print("a :" + v)


    @classmethod
    def save_b(cls, v):
        print("b :" + v)

    writers = [save_a, save_b, save_c]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Writer.save(1, [1, 2, 3])
```

Previous code results into the following error:

```
TypeError: 'classmethod' object is not callable
```

Does anybody know if what I'm trying to do is reachable? Or am I obliged to use regular methods and instanciate a Writer wherever I need to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also make it work by adding a wrapper class that is smarter about what calling whatever it's dealing with.

Since you mentioned in a comment that you're going to need to make the call to one of the`writers`multiple places, I've updated my answer to address this by adding a nested wrapper class to encapsulate the logic of calling the various callable types in one spot. This is a classic example of using OOP to apply the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle.

```
def save_c(v):
    print("c :" + v)

class Writer(object):
    @classmethod
    def save(cls, t, v):
        cls.writers[t](cls, v)

    @classmethod
    def save_a(cls, v):
        print("a :" + v)

    @staticmethod
    def save_b(v):
        print("b :" + v)

    def _wrapper(writer):
        if isinstance(writer, classmethod):
            return type('ClassmethodWrapper', (object,), {'__call__':
                        lambda self, cls, v: writer.__func__(cls, str(v))})()
        elif isinstance(writer, staticmethod):
            return type('StaticmethodWrapper', (object,), {'__call__':
                        lambda self, cls, v: writer.__func__(str(v))})()
        else:
            return type('VanillaWrapper', (object,), {'__call__':
                        lambda self, cls, v: writer(str(v))})()

    writers = list(map(_wrapper, (save_a, save_b, save_c)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Writer.save(0, [1, 2, 3])  # -> a :[1, 2, 3]
    Writer.save(1, [4, 5, 6])  # -> b :[4, 5, 6]
    Writer.save(2, [7, 8, 9])  # -> c :[7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: I like your answer. But if I need to use in more than a single place the `writers[t]` trick, the code gets lengthy.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you meant to use `@staticmethod` rather than `@classmethod`.

For more information, see [What is the difference between @staticmethod and @classmethod in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python)

Comment: Replacing `classmethod` decorators with `staticmethod` ones, and `cls` prefixes with `Writer` ones leads to a very similar sanction : `TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable`. So it's not as easy as it seems :P .

Comment: @GuillaumeLemaître: Nobody said it was *all* you had to do. It was just a pointer in what I thought (and still think) is the right direction.

Comment: Even though, you have to admit that your answer was not very helpful, considering the real issue here, as my comment pointed out. Answer from @martineau makes much more sense. At least, this is my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the inner `writers` attribute has to reference the `__func__` attribute of the class methods. And yes, we need here to use `staticmethod` decorators instead of `classmethod` ones in order to respect the same signature used for external calls. The following code works well:

```
def save_c(v):
    print("c :" + v)


class Writer(object):

    @staticmethod
    def save(t, v):
        Writer.writers[t](str(v))


    @staticmethod
    def save_a(v):
        print("a :" + v)


    @staticmethod
    def save_b(v):
        print("b :" + v)

    writers = [save_a.__func__, save_b.__func__, save_c]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Writer.save(0, [1, 2, 3])
    Writer.save(1, [1, 2, 3])
    Writer.save(2, [1, 2, 3])
```